# sending my form data to a subscription page via JavaScript, to a different server?

Tags: jquery

I have been reading up on Cross-site HTTP requests access here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control, **but** I'm an still lost with some of their JavaScript examples.

I know how jQuery and AJAX works with POST and Get data, but I am lost to understanding (if it's possible) for me to gain access in sending my form data from my web site, to another domain on another server.

I'm building a form for web site visitors to fill out on my domain.  On submit, the data of that form will be sent to a subscription page on another domain (another server). Is this all possible with jQuery and AJAX for modern browsers (no server side pages involved)?  What other front-end technologies do I need to accomplish this task?  I'm looking for simple.

If this is all possible, can my form data travel to the subscription page, without showing the subscription page? i.e. I still stay on my own web site with a "thank you for subscribing" notice?

Thanks for any advice to help me learn and grow in this area!

Comment: Did you try posting using a fully qualified URL, if so what happened?

Comment: I haven't posted anything yet because I have not found a good tutorial yet on how to setup a structure of sending my data to another server.  that is part of my question.  by default I know in javascript you are not allowed to do that.  so what has changed for us to actually acommplish this task?  that is also part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) restriction in browsers is quite hard to bypass. If you want to access a form processor that's on a different domain, you need to set on that domain the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. If it's not your server/domain, you can't do that.

Some form processors bypass CORS restrictions by adding a callback function to a JSONP response, but that also depends on the remote server configuration.

For example, Campaign Monitor allows sending registration data via AJAX by providing the JSONP option.

Comment: Thanks Marius, you are the first person to really explain what the heck is going on with all this cross origin policy requirements and things to consider.  thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I banged my head on the wall with this problem a few weeks ago (for a production site), so helping others not to feels natural.